# Specify the type for ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist

In Java, and Android, I end up using `ArrayList<String>` for the supplying list as I find them easier to use than the standard `String[]`. My real questions though are this:
What is the `<String>` portion of the `ArrayList<String>` called?
How can I create classes and use the `<>` [modifier]? (I don't know what it's actually called, so for now it's modifier).
Thanks!

Comment: Google java generics

Comment: It's called a _type parameter_.

Comment: This is not a specific question. This is Generic question and we won't be able to answer every aspect of Generic. Have study on Generic. (This is huge topic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<String>` part is the *type argument*. It provides a "value" of sorts for the *type parameter* which is the `E` in `ArrayList<E>`... in the same way that if you have a method:

```
public void foo(int x)
```

and you call it with:

```
foo(5)
```

the parameter is `x`, and the argument supplied is `5`. Type parameters and type arguments are the generic equivalent, basically.

See [section 4.5 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5) (and the links from it) for some more details - and the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for more information about generics than you could possibly want to read :)

Answer (score 8):

Here, you wil maybe see clearer:

```
ArrayList<TypeOfYourClass>
```

You can create a Person class and pass it to an ArrayList as this snippet is showing:

```
ArrayList<Person> listOfPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Comment: So much like you can create an Array like `MyClass[]`, you can also create `ArrayList<MyClass>`, getting the functionality of the ArrayList over the Array?

Comment: There are several features in the ArrayList which is a Collection class that you'll not find in the array type. For example you can find an "add" method, by which you can add objects dynamically to your list, you can find a remove method, a size() one, besides the fact that arrays' memories are allocated when instanciated and their size, hence, is fixed from the beginning, if you decalre an array of persons with size 20, you cannot add more than 20 persons to the array. Collections do.

Answer (score 3):

Supose you want an ArrayList to be filled only with Strings.
If you write:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");
```

You can be sure than if somebody tries to fill the arrayList with an int it will be detected in complile time.

So, generics are used in situations where you want enforce restrictions like this.

Answer (score 2):

The bit between `<>` is a type argument, and the feature is called [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look up the *generics* syntax for Java. That will set you straight (well, sort of; a lot of people find Java's approach inferior to C++ and C#).

Answer (score 1):

The  is the type parameter. In Java, you have to provide one of these when the class is written as a generic.

Here is an example of a Generic class definition

```
private class GNode<T>
{
    private T data;
    private GNode<T> next;

    public GNode(T data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

You can now create nodes of any type that you pass in. The T acts as a generic type parameter for your class definition. If you want to create a node of Integers, just do:

```
 GNode<Integer> myNode = new GNode<Integer>();
```

It should be noted that your type parameter must be an object. This works through Java's auto-boxing and auto-unboxing. This means that you cannot use java primitive types and you must use the corresponding classes instead.

```
Boolean instead of bool
Integer instead of int
Double instead of double 
etc...
```

Also, if you don't pass in a type parameter I'm pretty sure your code will still compile. But it won't work.